# how to edit button text in custom components in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

i have created custom components in flex where i have used a button,i want to change button text when i will use that component in other mmxl file how i can do that? thanks in advance below is code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just introduce a property for button label in your custom components like the following:

```
[Bindable]
public var buttonLabel:String = "Default Label";
```

And bind button's label in the same component with that property the following way:

```
<mx:Button label="{buttonLabel}" />
```

So the usage is pretty easy. Say your component name is MyComponent:

```
<MyComponent buttonLabel="My Custom Label" />
```

Hope this helps :)